# PYQT5 window only shows partial view

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am wirting a pyqt5 window but for some reason the window only shows partial view of what I want like in the image attached,
what is the problem with my code??

I have tried to resize my window but it still gives me partial view..

Can anyone help??[image]

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 500)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")


        self.listview = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listview.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10,10,200,300))
        self.listview.setObjectName("listview")

        path = r'\\user\folder' 

        self.fileModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel(self.centralwidget)
        self.fileModel.setRootPath(path)
        self.fileModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Files)
        self.listview.setModel(self.fileModel)
        self.listview.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.index(path))

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20,220,100,20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20,250,100,20))



        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
         _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
         MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "App"))
         self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "table for complete data?"))
         self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Get data"))
         MainWindow.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is caused because when you set a widget as a child it does not imply that he knows the size of the child, for example in your case self.centralwidget is a child of MainWindow, but MainWindow does not know the size of self.centralwidget asu self. centralwidget will have a size set by sizeHint. On the other hand only the children will be visible if the father is the right size to make them visible, and in your case self.centralwidget is so small that it does not make your children visible.

In these cases, it is advisable to use a qlayout, but the basic thing is to set the self.centralwidget as centralWidget of QMainWindow, which is a special widget that already has a qlayout.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 500)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listview = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listview.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10,10,200,300))
        self.listview.setObjectName("listview")

        path = r'\\user\folder' 

        self.fileModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel(self.centralwidget)
        self.fileModel.setRootPath(path)
        self.fileModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Files)
        self.listview.setModel(self.fileModel)
        self.listview.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.index(path))

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20,220,100,20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20,250,100,20))

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
         _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
         MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "App"))
         self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "table for complete data?"))
         self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Get data"))
         MainWindow.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Although a better option is to use a layout, and improve your code, we obtain:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("App")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.listview = QtWidgets.QListView()
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("table for complete data?")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Get data")
        path = r'\\user\folder' 
        self.fileModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel(self)
        self.fileModel.setRootPath(path)
        self.fileModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Files)
        self.listview.setModel(self.fileModel)
        self.listview.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.index(path))

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        lay.addWidget(self.listview)
        lay.addWidget(self.label)
        lay.addWidget(self.pushButton)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: That looks good, Thanks! Now I want to get the selected files' names in the QListview, so when I click the get data button, python will open these selected files by calling their names, how can I get the names?

Comment: @Cindy that is another question, create a new post and we will be happy to help (but I recommend to investigate before, probably already there is a similar question), On the other hand do not forget to mark my answer as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour]

Comment: @Cindy some feedback?

Comment: Sure, I have marked your answer and posted another question, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484241/get-selected-files-filenames-from-pyqt5-qlistview-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage the layout of your window. This can be easily done by using a [QGridLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 500)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.listview = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listview.setObjectName("listview")
        path = r'\\user\folder'

        self.fileModel = QtWidgets.QFileSystemModel(self.centralwidget)
        self.fileModel.setRootPath(path)
        self.fileModel.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot | QtCore.QDir.Files)
        self.listview.setModel(self.fileModel)
        self.listview.setRootIndex(self.fileModel.index(path))

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        # Adding a GridLayout (1 column), adding the widgets and sets a geometry. 
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)
        grid.addWidget(self.listview, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.label, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 0)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(grid)
        self.centralwidget.setGeometry(300,300,350,350)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
         _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
         MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "App"))
         self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "table for complete data?"))
         self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Get data"))
         MainWindow.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This results in this:

[image]